# Sharepoint New Item button returns a blank page when it supposed to return my custom form. What could possibly cause the issue?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Whenever I click "New Item" button on Sharepoint list to, of course, to create an item... it returns a blank page. Here's the screenshot of what it returns:

[image: screenshot]

I am the one who created this list, so I should have an access. My teammates can access the custom form I made whenever they click the New Item button except me. It all started when I got an error message after I modified my infopath form. It's about Web Part Maintenance.

My teammates told me to clear my browser's cache & cookies.. I did but to no avail.

Is there anyone who have also experienced this same issue? A help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem with your form.  You can revert the list to its out of the box form in the list settings page.
If you wish to troubleshoot it, could you post a screen shot of a Fiddler trace for when you're clicking the New button?

Answer (score 0):

Are you team mates are opening the same form?  if yes then try on private browser tab.

If no then please share the fidler and consol logs.